# Hazards in the wave in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog, fsm

Whilst running a testbench on a module that does the exponent operation (a^b) by using an FSM and a 32x32 multiplier
I get a wierd hazard on the wave of the FSM outputs (update_counter,busy,update_prod).

Why does the hazard happen?

The module of the multiplier is tested out and works fine, the hazard is stricktly related to the FSM
Hazard:

[image]

Code:

```
// Power Module
module power (
    input logic clk,              // Clock
    input logic reset,            // Reset
    input logic start,            // Start signal
    input logic[3:0] a,           // Input 
    input logic[2:0] b,           // Input 
    output logic busy,            // Power busy indication
    output logic[63:0] result     // Result
 );

// This module is calculating Result = a^b. 

// Local Variables. 
// Counter for Number of mult operations left. 
logic[4:0] counter;   
// Signals for mult.
logic mul_start, mul_busy, counter_clear, update_prod, clr_prod, counter_done, update_counter; 
// States for the FSM.
logic [1:0] cur_state, next_state;
// Inputs for the mult.
logic[31:0] b_input, a_input, product;
// Registers for the mult output.
logic[63:0]   mul_prod; 

// We want to assign the leg b of the mult 
// the input a as constant via b_input.
// Put your code here.
// ------------------
always_comb begin
    product=result;
    b_input=b;
    a_input=a;
end

// End of your code.

//Next, Declare the mult module we are going to use. 
// Put your code here.
// ------------------


mult32x32_fast mult(
    .busy(mul_busy),
    .product(mul_prod),
    .clk(clk),
    .reset(reset),
    .start(mul_start),
    .a(a_input),
    .b(product)
    );
    // End of your code.
    
    
    
// Initiating FFs Complete: 
always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
    if ( reset == 1'b1 ) begin
        cur_state<=2'b00;
    end
    else begin 
        cur_state<=next_state;
    end
    if (reset == 1'b1) begin
        counter <= 4'b00;
    end
    else begin 
        if (counter_clear == 1'b1) begin
            counter <= 4'b00;
        end
        else if ((counter < b_input - 1)&&update_counter==1'b1) begin
            counter <= counter + 1;
        end
    end
    if(reset==1'b1) begin
    result<=a_input;
    end
    else begin
        if(clr_prod==1'b1)begin
            result<=a;
        end
        else if(update_prod==1'b1)begin
            result<=mul_prod;
        end
        else begin
            result<=result;
        end
    end
end 
always_comb begin
    if (counter == b_input - 1) begin
        counter_done = 1'b1;
    end
    else begin
        counter_done = 1'b0;
    end

end

// Manage FSM Logic.
// We are going to use an FSM in order to manage 
// the multiplications. 
always_comb begin
    next_state=cur_state;
    mul_start=1'b0;
    counter_clear=1'b0;
    update_prod=1'b0;
    clr_prod=1'b0;
    busy=1'b0;
    update_counter=1'b0;
    case (cur_state) 
        2'b00: begin
            // Idle state - Waiting on 'start' signal.
            // Put your code here.
            // ------------------
            if(start==1'b0) begin
                next_state=2'b00;

            end
            else begin
                next_state=2'b01;
                clr_prod=1'b1;
                counter_clear=1'b1;
            end

            // End of your code.
        end
    
        2'b01: begin
            // Initiating state - Updating input for the mult 
            // and starting its operation.
            // Put your code here.
            // ------------------
            if(counter_done==1'b1)begin
                next_state=2'b00;
            end
            else begin
                next_state=2'b10;
                mul_start=1'b1;
                busy=1'b1;
            end
        
            // End of your code.
        end
        
        2'b10: begin
            // Waiting state - Waiting for the mult to finish 
            // How can you indicate?
            // Put your code here.
            // ------------------
            if(mul_busy==1'b1)begin
                next_state=2'b10;
                busy=1'b1;
            end
            else begin
                next_state=2'b01;
                update_prod=1'b1;
                update_counter=1'b1;
                busy=1'b1;
            end
        
            // End of your code.
        end            
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

TestBench:

```
// testbench for the power module
module power_tb;

logic clk;            // Clock
logic reset;          // Reset
logic start;          // Start signal
logic [3:0] a;        // Input a
logic [2:0] b;        // Input b
logic busy;           // Multiplier busy indication
logic [63:0] result;  // Miltiplication product


/* Check the hardware you wrote with the two cases you chose.*/
// Put your code here
// ------------------
power uut(
.busy(busy),
.result(result),
.clk(clk),
.reset(reset),
.start(start),
.a(a),
.b(b)
);

initial begin
    clk=1'b1;
end
always begin
    #1 clk=~clk;
end

initial begin
    reset=1'b0;
    @(posedge clk);
    reset=1'b1;
    start=1'b0;
    a=0;
    b=0;
    repeat (4) begin
        @(posedge clk);
    end
    reset=1'b0;
    @(posedge clk);
    start=1'b1;
    a={1'b0,1'b0,1'b1,1'b0};
    b={1'b1,1'b1,1'b0};
    @(posedge clk);
    start=1'b0;
    @(negedge busy);
    @(posedge clk);
    start=1'b1;
    a={1'b1,1'b0,1'b1,1'b0};
    b={1'b0,1'b1,1'b1};
    @(posedge clk);
    start=1'b0;
    @(negedge busy);
end
// End of your code

endmodule
```

Comment: yes thats a zero time glitch, btw thank you for your help and i dont think i want these glitches although they arent affecting the logic of the system i dont think they should happen

Answer (score 1):

You need to use non-blocking assignments in your testbench, or change your inputs away from the `posedge clk`. That will get rid of your glitches.

```
initial begin
    reset=1'b0;
    @(negedge clk); //move away from posedge
    reset=1'b1;
    start=1'b0;
    a=0;
    b=0;
    repeat (4) @(posedge clk);
    reset <=1'b0; // no longer a race
    @(posedge clk);
    start<=1'b1; 
    a<={1'b0,1'b0,1'b1,1'b0};
    b<={1'b1,1'b1,1'b0};
    ...
```

Comment: can you explain with a bit more details  the "change your inputs away from the posedge clk" part? I don't think i've understood what you meant by that.

Comment: if you notice the hazards happen only after the assignments when the fsm starts running, so i dont know if that is the main issue that is causing the hazards, you can also see that im waiting between changing each input so there isnt really a race. so im not 100% sure that fixes the issue

Comment: You are not showing `mult32x32_fast `, so I don't know how that might be contributing to the glitches.

Comment: Well, you are right but mult32x32 is not dependant on the other parts, and if you notice the glitches are only occouring on the FSM outputs, so i think it might have to be with the switch case but i dont know at what part.

Comment: The glitches can only come from the FSM `always_comb` block inputs that are not assigned using non-blocking assignments. That could be `start` and `counter_done` coming from the testbench, or `mul_busy` coming from `mult32x32_fast`.